# Ubuntu 16.04 - HP Envy x360 WiFi issue Intel 7265NGW

Tags: networking, drivers, hp

I have an issue with the WiFi on an HP Envy x360 which uses the Intel 7265NGW. Firstly the WiFi was disabled, so I ran:

```
sudo rmmod acer_wmi
```

Which meant I was able to enable WiFi and connect. The issue I am having is that it will randomly disable the WiFi and I have to re-run the above command to get back online.

Any ideas on why this would be happening and how I could fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply blacklist it:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

Comment: That seems to have done it - thank you very much for the speedy help.